# Cerrar dinámicamente workbook de excel con vba

Tags: excel, vba

En resumidas cuentas, intento automatizar un proceso de creación de informes, las macros en los libros individuales funciona muy bien, tengo un inconveniente y por mas que he consultado la documentación de Microsoft o foros, preguntas en comunidades no logro entender porque me sucede...

**Funcionamiento**
Tengo 3 libros, "DataCenter.xlsm" que se encarga de consultar y actualizar esas mismas consultas para obtener información desde una base de datos SQL Server. "CompanyData.xlsm" el cual contiene información que mes a mes se debe renovar con los nuevos listados recibidos, este archivo se encarga de encontrar posibles registros que no coinciden con los datos en "DataCenter.xlsm", si todos los datos están ok emite respuesta booleana `true` a "DataCenter.xlsm", entonces desde "DataCenter.xlsm" ordeno abrir el libro final "AutomaticReport.xlsm" el cual se encarga de hacer una unión de los  datos entre "DataCenter.xlsm" y "CompanyData.xlsm" para finalmente generar el informe.

**Código del archivo DataCenter.xlsm**

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Definiendo variables booleanas para determinar resultados de ejecución

Dim responseUpdateData As Boolean
Dim directoryPath, separator, fileNameOpen As String
Dim respCompanyData As Boolean

respCompanyData = False
directoryPath = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path
separator = Application.PathSeparator
fileNameOpen = directoryPath & separator & "AutomaticReport.xlsm"


'responseUpdateData = RefreshAllQueries()

'Guardando cambios actualizados
'ThisWorkbook.Save

Call CompanyData.ResultVerificacion(respCompanyData) 'Llamo a la macro guardad en CompanyData.xlsm mediante una referencia 
'(Al estar como referencia a este archivo CompanyData.xlsm no se puede cerrar antes que este archivo "DataCenter.xlsm")

'Respuesta llega como TRUE
If respCompanyData Then
    Application.Workbooks.Open Filename:=fileNameOpen, UpdateLinks:=0 'Voy al archivo final para generar el informe
'sin actualizar los links a los archivos externos
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

**Código del archivo AutomaticReport.xlsm**

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim Fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Dim respUpdating, respIsOpen As Boolean
Dim fileNameClose1, fileNameClose2 As String

fileNameClose1 = "DataCenter.xlsm"
fileNameClose2 = "CompanyData.xlsm"

If isOpen(fileNameClose1) Then
    Application.Workbooks(fileNameClose1).Close True 'Aqui es donde se detiene la macro y no se el motivo

End If
If isOpen(fileNameClose2) Then
    Application.Workbooks(fileNameClose1).Close True
End If

respUpdating = updateData()

If respUpdating = True Then
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    Call createReport
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

ThisWorkbook.Close True
End Sub
```

**El Inconveniente**
(Ver linea comentada donde digo que se presenta el inconveniente en el archivo AutomaticReport.xlsm) El archivo "DataCenter.xlsm" se encuentra abierto, la función reconoce que está abierto, sin embargo intento cerrarlo, se cierra y no continua el flujo del código, he puesto `Debug.Print` para evaluar si continúa y en realidad se detiene justo ahí, no continua el flujo del código.

Ya intenté cerrarlo directamente en el mismo archivo "DataCenter.xlsm" con `ThisWorkbook.close True` después de abrir el archivo "AutomaticReport.xlsm", sucede lo mismo no me cierra el archivo "CompanyData.xlsm", de igual forma intenté cerrarlo haciendo una activación previa del libro, guardando y cerrando.

```
If isOpen(fileNameClose1) Then
    
    With Application.Workbooks(fileNameClose1)
            .Activate
            .Save
            .Close
    End With  'El archivo se activa, guarda datos, se cierra pero no ejecuta la siguiente linea
    
    Debug.Print "cerrado.. DataCenter.xlsm"  'Esta línea no ejecuta y ninguna de las que siguen 
    
End If

If isOpen(fileNameClose2) Then
    With Application.Workbooks(fileNameClose2)
            .Activate
            .Save
            .Close
    End With
    Debug.Print "cerrado.. CompanyData.xlsm"
End If
```

Agradezco de sus conocimientos y comentarios para lograr cerrar ambos archivos.

Despues del cierre de estos archivos viene la actualización de las consultas en "AutomaticReport.xlsm" y la verdad no quisiera tenerlos abiertos, ya que me pone bastante lento el equipo.

Intenté dejarlos abiertos y cerrarlos luego de finalizar todos los procesos de manera forzada con `Application.Quit` sin embargo al volver a abrir el archivo "DataCetner.xlsm" me aparecen las alertas de archivos recuperados por mal cierre de los mismos, con autorrecuperación.

He intentado varias maneras y pues no he logrado lo que quiero, agradezco de sus comentarios para encontrar el error.

Comment: ¿probaste a debugearlo step by step con F8 para ver el momento exacto en el que abandona el código?

Comment: Saludos @Esei si, efectivamente por eso me di cuenta del punto exacto hasta donde llega el código y se detiene, además porque le tengo implementado una función para ir dejando un log en un txt de los pasos que se van completando. En realidad no se porque se me detiene el código en ese punto

Comment: Probando el código desde el libro donde está la macro paso a paso funciona, cierra los dos workbooks, y sigue sin embargo cuando lo punto a debuguear desde la macro del otro libro que viene. Ahí es donde no pasa.

Comment: En ese caso me temo que sin ver los archivos no es posible diagnosticar nada. ¿Puedes subirlos a algún sitio con solo la parte que te falla?

Comment: @Esei Muchas gracias por su intención de apoyarme, sin embargo por políticas de privacidad de la información para con los clientes de la empresa donde laboro, no me es posible compartir los archivos, de momento cambié la manera o el ciclo de ejecución del algoritmo.